# no graphical login prompt and VM lockup after ubuntu upgrade 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, xorg

I successfully upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 VM (Virtualbox 6.1 hosted on MacOS) to 20.04, but the gnome display manager login prompt doesn't appear.  I see the ubuntu splash screen, and then it goes black and unresponsive.

X11 worked fine before the upgrade with a default run level of 5.

I can boot with runlevel 3, and manually run startx from tty1 after that without error.  If I try telinit 5, then I also see an ubuntu splash screen, then black screen.  About a minute after that, any ssh sessions that I have active become unresponsive, and I also cannot tty switch back to the console with F1-6.  At that point I have to powerdown the VM, and either let the `fsck` run or restore from a previous snapshot.

The graphics adapter, as seen in ubuntu is:

```
   $ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter [80ee:beef]
```

Are there any known issues that would explain this?  If not, I'd appreciate some diagnostic tips.

Comment: can you change your  Graphics Controller to  VMSVGA?  https://arcolinux.com/how-to-set-virtualbox-6-the-correct-way-graphical-controller-workflow/

Comment: I tried that adapter change, while also bumping up the video memory as suggested in the video.  It turns out that it was the video memory that was the issue, as I'm now also to run 'telinit 5' with the original adapter, but more video memory configured for the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran 'dmesg -w' in an ssh session while I tried 'sudo telinit 5' in the VM display, and saw the following message before the machine became unresponsive:

[  219.138358] [drm] Error -12 pinning new fb, out of video mem?

Bumping up the video memory to 32Mb seems to handle the issue (despite the fact that vbox says that's not a valid setting.)